# How to update vuetify to latest version in Nuxt JS?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

how do I update vuetify in NuxtJS to the latest version? I have try to update using the command given in the module page but the latest release of the nuxt-module/vuetify is only until 1.0.0 Beta.

I have try to run `npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/vuetify@next` it is only update until the current release version. And I have try to use the solution that use the vuetify as a plugin but still not working.

The module i currently use is from `https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module`

I want my current vuetify version to be the latest vuetify.

Comment: @nuxtjs/vuetify@next will install latest vuetify beta version e.g. vuetify-2.beta1

Comment: ok thanks sir i was confuse before inside the package mention it Vuetify 2.0.0 and finally solve thanks sir.